# How would you describe a poorly worn sweater?

Tags: single-word-requests

What word or words would you use to describe a sweater that was put on poorly, perhaps a little twisted, with too much fabric in front of one shoulder and too little in front of the other? Imagine the wearer's parent or spouse saying "Your sweater is _____. Let me fix it," which they would do by tugging and straightening it.

(My mother used the words pronounced "k'naitch'd" and "fah-shtrayt" to describe the misaligned sweater. I thought they were Yiddish, like many words I learned from her, but recently learned she made them up.)

Comment: https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/askew

Answer (score 1):

Farshimmelt or Farschimmelt is Yiddish but refers to a state of mind rather than a physical object. But in such an adaptive language it would do just fine. Found in wordreference.com.

The garment is ill fitting not because of the size but the orientation, but only the current condition. One might describe it as a "State of disorder" and be done with it.